# Copy text in a object to be used on another object By PHP

Tags: php

Hey Guys You can see the code below
I want the "This text is fixed" to be copied to all "This is a text" in the remaining part by PHP

```
<div class = "movies">
<a href = " This text is fixed "><img src = "This is a text/media/poster.png" alt = "This is a text"><hr color = "blue" size = "3"><font><center>This is a Text</center></font></a>
</div>
```

Comment: if you just want to replace the text, use find & replace feature of any text editor.. And if you want to do it using PHP script, then **str_replace** would help. It will be great if you can show exactly how you want it to look after replacing and also show us what are you trying

Comment: The details are a bit scarce. Is this a template of some kind? Why do you want to replace text in an HTML tag using PHP? Wouldn't JavaScript/jQuery be sufficient for the job? Please provide some more context and details of what is it that you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use The [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to do this

```
 <?php
    $html="
    <div class ='movies'>
    <a href = 'This text is fixed '>
    <img src = 'This is a text/media/poster.png' alt = 'This is a text'>
    <hr color = 'blue' size = '3'>
    <center>This is a Text</center>
    </a>
    </div>";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
        $href= $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
        $node->setAttribute('alt',$href);
        }
    }
     echo $dom->saveHtml($dom), PHP_EOL;
     ?>
```